# JceSecurity illegalAccessError for internal in Java 11

Tags: java

I am just starting to use Java 11 and modules.  I am confused as to why I get the following error.  Since it is a java class using an internal why doesn't it have access to the internal class?

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.crypto.JceSecurity (in unnamed module @0x6bb7cce7) cannot access class jdk.internal.util.StaticProperty (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.util to unnamed module @0x6bb7cce7

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue from what I though was a answer to this question but at the moment I cannot see any responses to my question in stack overflow.  I must be doing something wrong.

The answer is to use the --add-opens flag of the jvm.

--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED

I was able to add this to the run configuration in my IDE and it resolved the error.